# set_post_thumbnail_size vs add_image_size

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

What is the difference between set_post_thumbnail_size and add_image_size? Is set_post_thumbnail_size for all images, and add_image_size for sizing images individually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When an image is uploaded in WordPress, it is saved in its original size, and also as some **resized copies** in different sizes. In this way it becomes easy to use different sizes, of the same image, for different purposes.

By default, WordPress creates 3 copies in 3 different sizes:

- `'thumb'`
- `'medium'`
- `'large'`

The size in pixels for these 3 sizes can be set in the WordPress dashboard, under the menu `Settings -> Media`.

Now, the function [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) is used to register a new size, that adds to the 3 defaults.

Every size registered can be retrieved using its name, in some WordPress function, e.g. [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), [`wp_get_attachment_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_link/).

All these functions accept a parameter `$size` that should be the name of one of the registered sizes (one of the 3 standards, or one of the custom sizes registered with `add_image_size`).

If `'full'` is used as `$size` argument, the original image is returned, the one not resized.

In addition to the functions mentioned above, there are two other functions that make use of image sizes: [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) and [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/).

These two functions get (the first) and echo (the second) the image that is set as "Featured Image" for a post.

What is returned (or echoed) by these functions is a full `img` html tag, something like

```
<img scr="http://www.example.com/wp-content/2013/08/image-200x200.jpg" />
```

So, which is the size used?

If a `$size` is passed as 2nd argument (1st is `$postid`), then these functions return the image in that size. Otherwise, these functions search for a image size registered with the name: `post-thumbnail`.

This is not one of the 3 default sizes, in fact, it is the 4th standard size (the 5th is considered `full`) and you can register it calling [`set_post_thumbnail_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail_size/).

So

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop );
```

is a shortcut for

```
add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', $width, $height, $crop );
```

If you haven't called `set_post_thumbnail_size` (which means the size `'post-thumbnail'` is not created), WordPress will use the size `thumb`, and if even this size is not available, WordPress will use the original image, the one not resized.

Registering custom image sizes can be very helpful when designing a theme, but it's important not to abuse: **every** uploaded image is copied and resized for all the sizes registered, so registering a lot of sizes will heavily slow down the image uploading process.

A note:

Be aware that when WordPress creates scaled copies of an image, it never enlarges it, but only makes smaller copies: e.g. if the original image is 400x500px, and the 'medium' image size is 800x600px, medium size and larger are **not** created.

So registering an image size never gives the security that an image file for every size registered *actually* exists in the WordPress content folder. Even because registered image sizes easily change: changing settings, switching themes, etc.

When an image size changes, for any reason, the change has an effect on the images uploaded **after** that change; images uploaded before don't change dimensions and are **not** rescaled and resaved.

If one needs to rely on specific image sizes after some images are already uploaded (e.g. after changing themes), then the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) will be a life saver.

Comment: Awesome. I would have clicked 5 times because of your answer but the site does not allow it. Thanls.

Comment: You are welcome, one is ok anymore :)

Comment: Just one more questoin: What if I have not called set_post_thumbnail_size (which means that the size 'post-thumbnail' is not created, then I call the_post_thumbnail. What is going to happen? (because the_post_thumbnail will try to use post-thumbnail as a param).

Comment: @G.M., Thumbs up for a lucid explanation

Comment: This answer is very helpful! However, I think this:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); If you haven't called set_post_thumbnail_size (which means the size 'post-thumbnail' is not created), WordPress will use the size thumb, and if even this size is not available, WordPress will use the original image, the one not resized.`

...is incorrect. In my experience testing this, if `set_post_thumbnail_size()` has not been called, WP falls back to the full size image.

Answer (score 1):

From Codex:

`set_post_thumbnail_size`

> Set the default Featured Image (formerly Post Thumbnail) dimensions.
>   To register additional image sizes for Featured Images use:
>   add_image_size().

`add_image_size`

> Registers a new image size. This means that WordPress will create a
>   copy of the Featured Image (formerly known as post thumbnail) with the
>   specified dimensions when you upload a new image.

Comment: Can I use add_image_size without using set_post_thumbnail_size?

Comment: Yes, of course.