# What is the different between an attachment in wp_posts and an attachment in wp_postmeta?

Tags: post-meta, attachments, woocommerce-offtopic

After the [Woocommerce dummy products](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/importing-woocommerce-dummy-data/) are imported, I notice that in the database, there are different records in different tables but point to THE SAME photo attachment.

The question is why? What are the differences between those records? Is that a duplication/redundancy in data storing?

Let's take `post_id=16` as below snapshot. We would see as below.

1. In table `wp_posts`, the id=16 post has `post_type`=attachment and its `guid` points to `T1_front_1.jpg` image.

[image]

2. In table `wp_postmeta`, the one with post_id=16 is also taking the `meta_key` as `_wp_attachment_file` and `meta_value` points to **the same image** `T1_front_1.jpg`.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

## An attachment *is* a Post

The posts table contains information on the attachment *post*.

In WordPress every uploaded media has it's own post entry, where `post_type` is `'attachment'` and `post_status` is `'inherit'`.

In fact, you can get attachment post types using functions used to get other post types, like post, page or any CPT.

That includes `WP_Query`, `get_posts()` and `get_post()`.

### What's in `posts` table

For every attachment post

- `post_title` column is used for attachment *title*
- `post_excerpt` is used for attachment *caption*
- `post_content` is used for attachment *description*

Note that attachment post type may have a `post_parent` that points to the ID of the post where the attachment was uploaded from.

For example:

```
get_posts( 'post_type=attachment&post_parent=10' );
```

Retrieve all the post objects for attachments loaded from the edit page of the post with ID `10`;

## An attachment is *not only* a Post

However, there is information for media (especially images) that simply doesn't fit the posts table.

All this information is stored in the postmeta table, where the `post_id` column refers to the attachment row in the posts table.

### What's in `postmeta` table

For example, the `"alt"` attribute is stored in a meta field that has the key **`'_wp_attachment_image_alt'`**.

The meta field with key **`'_wp_attached_file'`** contains the relative path (to content folder) of the uploaded file.

That is used to build the attachment URL and path, in functions like [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/), [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), [`get_attached_file()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) and so on.

Finally, the field `'_wp_attachment_metadata'` contains different information (in a serialized array in the database):

- The image size (under keys `'width'` and `'height'`)
- Information about **intermediate sizes**

### Intermediate sizes

In fact, every time an image is uploaded, WordPress creates different copies of the image in different sizes.

Please read **[this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108572/set-post-thumbnail-size-vs-add-image-size/108583#108583)** for more details.

The key `"sizes"` in the `'_wp_attachment_metadata'` field contain an array with information on all generated images: the file created, the size (width and height) and so on.

Note that the preferred way to get information from `'_wp_attachment_metadata'` is not using the *common* `get_post_meta()` but the specific [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/), as it triggers a filter.

If you are interested in the information about a specific generated image, the function [`image_get_intermediate_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_get_intermediate_size/) will be handy.

### Use specific functions

Generally speaking, if you need information on an attachment, use the specific functions and avoid pulling data from the database; it is harder and does not triggers hooks, possibly breaking core, theme and plugins compatibility.

There are *a lot* of functions in WordPress to work with attachments, [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=attachment&post_type[]=wp-parser-function) should give you an idea...

However, main functions are all listed in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination in full. In brief may you tell the differences again please. I'm messed up.

Comment: The 2 tables contain different information. Post table contains *some* info, postmeta table contains *some other* info. To know the *full story* about an attachment you need information from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

First is showing the attachment file path, second is  file attributes size, type, height, width etc.

Thanks

attachment in wp_post shows the attachment basic details title, time, author etc.

wp_postmeta shows attachment all other details for example attachment would be text, pdf, image etc so it having different meta data for different types of posts.

Thanks